# get time taken to buffer while playing a video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaplayercontroller

When we play an online video through MPMoviePlayerViewController there will be some buffer time in all the cases. Is there any way by which we can capture the buffer time.
My perception was that there should be some callback methods which gets invoke at start and stop buffering but I did not find any in documentation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The movieplayer sends lots of notifications by the look of it.

Comment: yes but I couldn't find any one related to buffering. Please guide me incase you know any by the help of which I can know the start and stop time of buffer.

Comment: isn't the buffering time the difference between the time the view controller was loaded and the time you get a `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notification telling you playback has started?